# How can I hide axis numbers but keep title and grid lines in my plotly.js scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I posted this over at the Plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-hide-axis-numbers-but-not-title-or-grid/77800. Since I rarely get responses there, I'm also posting it here.

I have a scatter plot and I'd like to hide axis numbers but not the grid or the axis title. How can I do that?

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

Notice that the Y axis has a title, axis numbers, and grid lines. Notice that the x axis has none of these.

Here is the code for this:

```
var layout = {
    ...
    xaxis: {
        visible: false,
        showgrid: true,
        title: 'driver'
    },
    yaxis: {
        visible: true,
        title: 'kWh',
        showgrid: true
    }
}
```

Note that I have title set to a value and showgrid set to true in both axis. The only difference is visible is set to false for the x axis and true for the y axis. So setting visible to false seems to hide everything, which is not what I want. I only want to hide the numbers (ideally, I'd like to keep the tick marks if that's possible).

How can I hide the numbers of the axis but keep the title and grid lines?

Thank you!

Comment: If by axis numbers you mean the tick labels, they can be hidden by setting [`showticklabels: false`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-showticklabels),  [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/35ds1oqx/)

Answer (score 0):

Kikon's comment above answers this question.